# Keypress in not read in visual basic 2010/2012

Tags: vb.net

My app is based on Visual Basic 2010/2012 (all its codes are same for both the languages). I'm trying to do certain things when either the `'F' or 'G'` is pressed from keyboard. I've tried all the things like using `Keypress, keydown and  keyup events` but they all didn't work.

Here is a sample code of my app. This just shows which key was pressed by the user in a message box and this also doesn't work i.e. nothing happens, not even an error message.

```
   Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown

    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Control AndAlso (e.KeyCode = Keys.F)) Then
        MessageBox.Show("pressed F")
    ElseIf (e.KeyCode = Keys.Control AndAlso (e.KeyCode = Keys.B)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("pressed B")
    End If
End Sub`
```

Comment: Have you set the keypreview property of the form?

Comment: KeyDown is the correct choice. Just enable KeyPreview, as @Tony mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on optimizing the `KeyDown` handler, using DRY principle (=don't repeat yourself):

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
  If Not e.Control Then Exit Sub
  Select Case e.KeyCode
    Case Keys.F : MessageBox.Show("Ctrl-F")
    Case Keys.B : MessageBox.Show("Ctrl-B")
  End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting KeyPreview() to True for your **Form**, as already pointed out by @Tony Hopkinson, here is how to correctly check for Ctrl-F or Ctrl-B:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.F Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl-F")
    ElseIf e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.B Then
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl-B")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you meant `KeyPreview`, not `KeyDown` there.

Answer (score 0):

In keypressed

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
dim kc as string = e.KeyChar

if kc = "F" OR kc = "G" then msgbox "Horeeee"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks to all for your kind help.